# Using the same services ID identifier as App ID

Tags: ios, apple-developer

When trying to register a new services ID, I see the following text:

> We recommend using a reverse-domain name style string (i.e.,
>   com.domainname.appname). It cannot contain an asterisk (*).

I have an App and associated Bundle and App ID. I made the bundle ID and app ID the same. Call it `X.Y.Z`. Now, I want to add the Sign in With Apple functionality, but when I use `X.Y.Z` for the services ID identifier, I get an error:

> An attribute in the provided entity has invalid value An App ID with
>   Identifier 'X.Y.Z' is not available. Please enter a different string.

Could someone confirm that **I cannot** use the same App/ Bundle ID for the service ID identifier, or that I might be doing **something else** wrong.

---

I have checked this bundle ID/ App ID is owned by the same account. I noticed a few other people who had 2 accounts in their Xcodes which they mixed up. I only have 1 account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out you can't use the same ID for both applications and services. I just made a unique identifier for the service, and it works fine.